# Toggle Display Conditional of Page Height

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this toggle display code that works perfectly:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.style.display == 'block')
        x.style.display = 'none';
    else
        x.style.display = 'block';
}
```

I am using this toggle display as a drop down for a search box on a sticky nav. My sticky nav is offset at `300 pixels` and when the page gets above that the toggle stays displayed, how can I -  `x.style.display = 'none';` - according to the page height?

I have this so far which doesn't seem to be working.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if ((window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 300) && (x.style.display == 'block'))
        x.style.display = 'none';
    else
        x.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: can you please share your js fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a problem with your conditional:

```
(window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 300)
```

Javascript is trying to evaluate each side of the logical OR, and only the right-hand bit tests `<=300`.  To write it another way, it's currently evaluating:

```
(window.pageYOffset) OR (document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 300)
```

I think you want something more like this:

```
(window.pageYOffset <=300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop <= 300)
```

I'd be more confident if I could confirm it in a fiddle, but I hope it helps either way.

Comment: `(window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) <= 300` works as well, it's just about the brackets